# Plotting ||A-xx'||^2 in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the function ||A-xx'||^2 in MATLAB.
Where A is a 2x2 identity matrix and x is 2x1 vector.
I think I need to use the surf function, but I am not sure how to use it.
Can anyone suggest how to proceed?

I tried the following code, but the dimensions of A and xx' does not match

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:1,-1:0.1:1);
A=eye(2);
Z = norm(A-[X.^2 X.*Y;X.*Y Y.^2])^2;
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you google for this problem? MATLAB has lots of examples online, including plots really similar to this. Look for example at the documentation of `surf`: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html

Comment: please add your code so we can see your attempt

Comment: Done. Added the code